# Pythonでリストの中の値を順に代入する方法

Tags: python

以前の質問で、レピュニット数を表す方法を教えていただきました。

[Pythonを使ってレピュニット数を表現し、整数問題を解きたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74777)

その次に、素数を順に代入していきたいのですが、うまくコードが書けません。
具体的には、リストの中に、指定した数字以下の素数を入れるところまではできています。
前の質問に倣って、そのリストをpと名づけたのですが、そのpの中の値をを順に代入していく方法がわかりません。

以下、以前の質問を引用:

> 以下の式を割り切れるような素数pを求めるという問題を解きたいのですが、レピュニット数(と思われる)をPythonでどのように処理すればいいのかわかりません。
>
> ```
> 1+10+10^2+・・・+10^(p-1)
> ```

なお、レピュニット数を `int('1' * p)` と表すことができることは教えていただいたのでわかっています。

以下コードです。

```py
import math

def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2: return False
    elif num == 2: return True
    elif num % 2 == 0: return False

    for i in range(3, math.floor(math.sqrt(num))+1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False

    return True

def callIsPrime(input_num=1000):
    numbers = []
   
    for i in range(1, input_num):
        if isPrime(i):
            numbers.append(i)

    return numbers

p = callIsPrime(1000)

print (int('1' * p) / p)
```

Comment: 「うまくコードが書けません」とのことですが、現在のコードを掲載いただかないと状況が第三者には全く分かりませんので、コードを掲載してください。

Comment: コードを追加いたしました。みていただければと思います。

Comment: `CallIsPrime` 関数で `for ... in range(...)` を使われていますが、それと同じ様にすれば良いのではないでしょうか。`for p in callIsPrime(1000): print(int('1' * p) % p)`

Comment: ところで、素数列を求めるには [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) というパッケージを利用することでも可能です。具体的には [SymPy primerange](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=primerange#sympy.ntheory.generate.primerange) を使います。`from sympy import primerange` としておいて、`callIsPrime(1000)` を `primerange(1, 1000)` に置き換えます。

Comment: @metropolis 様 そうなんですね！！素数を表すのも調べたものをとりあえず貼り付けたのみで、深く理解できていなかったので、これからじっくり理解していこうと思います。追加情報もありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

@metropolis さんよりコメントでいただいた

```
for p in callIsPrime(1000): print(int('1' * p) % p)
```

で解決いたしました。

Comment: 具体的な解決方法を説明されると他の方の役にも立つかと思います。

Comment: `for p in callIsPrime(1000): print(int('1' * p) % p)`
で解決いたしました。
初歩的な質問となってしまい申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 回答の方に追記してもらえませんか？現状では評価の変更が出来ないので、お手数ですがお願いいたします。

Comment: hata様が編集してくださいました。ありがとうございます